# Определить какой UNIX сигнал получил процесс

Tags: linux

Есть ли способ определить какой unix сигнал получил процесс?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, а так сам процесс может отловить посланный ему сигнал.

Comment: Не знаю что ещё уточнять, к примеру у меня есть программа которая получает сигнал и завершается, мне нужно посмотреть какой тип сигнала её завершает.

Comment: Программа Ваша, т.е. код известен?

Comment: Если не посмертно (тогда в status в waitpid), то только ловить все сигналы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из руководства [**bash**(1)](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=bash&category=1):

> Возвращаемым значением простой команды является её статус выхода или
>   128+**n**, если команда завершена сигналом **n**.

Таким образом можно выяснить номер сигнала, который получил процесс (если он при этом соизволил завершиться). Таблицу соответствия номеров сигналов и их названий можно вывести командной `kill -l`, код возврата последней команды можно узнать с помощью `echo $?`.

Comment: По-хорошему надо использовать `waitpid()` как оно там в `bash` называется.